# setState via function text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Unable to declare setState via the function. And I can’t understand what the mistake is.

```
export default class App extends Component {
state = {
    text: ' ',
};

text = () => {
    this.setState({ text: 'Good afternoon' });
}    

render() {

    return ()
}
}
```

When I declare setState in the standard way through

```
this.setState({
text: 'Good afternoon' 
})
```

then everything works as it should. But the declaration through the function does not work. Why?
I need to declare setState through a function.

Comment: What do you mean by not work? Is it not setting the state or does it return an undefined or is setState undefined or is the function not found?

Comment: You have to invoke your "text" function in order to have your text state change. `text()`

Comment: needs more clarity

Comment: setState DOES NOT SET THE STATE